# How are we actually supposed to include our OpenCL code?

Tags: opencl

How are we actually ***supposed*** to include our OpenCL code in our C projects?

We can't possibly be *supposed* to ship our .cl files along with our executable for the executable to find them and load them at runtime, because that's stupid, right?

We can't be *supposed* to use some stringify macro because a) that's apparently not portable/leads to undefined behaviour and b) it all breaks down if you use commas not enclosed in brackets like when defining many variables of the same type, I've spent an hour here looking for a solution to that and there doesn't seem to be one that actually works and c) that's kind of stupid.

Are we expected to write our code into C string literals like `"int x, y;\n" "float4 p;\n"`? Because I'm not doing that. Are we supposed to do a C include-style hexdump of our .cl files? That seems inconvenient. What are we actually supposed to do?

It's bad enough that all these approaches basically mean that you have to ship your program with your OpenCL code essentially open sourced when your OpenCL code is probably the last thing you want open sourced, on top of it it seems every OpenCL project I've seen uses one of the approaches listed above, it just doesn't seem right at all, it's like the people who made OpenCL forgot about something.

Comment: Here is a magic macro for you: `#define QUOTE(...) #__VA_ARGS__`. In my experience IDEs and debuggers have problems with it but other than that it is a nice portable hack.

Comment: As a side note: If you license/patent your OpenCL code correctly you will have no issue even if shipping the source. Sure, someone may try steal it, but you will be a rich man if they do. Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

This thread: [OpenCL bytecode running on another card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279150/opencl-bytecode-running-on-another-card) mentions SPIR, a *"platform-portable intermediate representation for OpenCL device programs"*. Other than that, you are basically restrained to the options you already mentioned.

Personally, I began to use C++11 raw string literals to get rid of my nasty stringify-macros. Don't know if C++ is an option for you, however.

Concerning your rejection of the *"ship our .cl files along with our executable"* approach: I don't see why this is inherently stupid -- the CL "shaders" are an application resource like all other separate files beside the executable, and thus are part of the "application bundle". It's perfectly reasonable to have such kind of files, and each operating system has its way to deal with it (in win32, the program directory is the bundle https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110620-00/?p=10393 , OSX has its own bundle concept, etc...).

Now, if you are worried about other people peeking into your OpenCL code, you can still apply some obfuscation methods (e.g. encrypt your .cl-files by a key which is more or less cleverly hidden in your executable).

[edit/sidenote]: We could also investigate how other companies deal with this issue in the context of, for example, OpenGL/Direct3D shaders. In my limited experience, gaming companies tend to dump their shaders in text form somewhere in their application directory, for all to see (and even to tamper with). So in the gaming world at least, there is no great deal of secrecy in that respect... Wonder what adobe or CAD software companies do in their professional software.

Comment: encrypting the files is rather useless. the unencrypted string is passed to the cl lib/driver which a user with ease can exchange with a logger. evil will find a way.